# Is it possible to set the source IP when sending UDP packets from node red

Tags: node.js, udp, node-red, static-ip-address

I am running node red on an ubuntu server and I have configured one of the network adapters to have several IP addresses, like this:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
    enp0s8:
       dhcp4: no
       addresses:
         - 192.168.25.9/24
         - 192.168.25.23/24
         - 192.168.25.43/24
         - 192.168.25.45/24
         - 192.168.25.67/24
  version: 2
```

The idea is that I want to use node red to simulate several controllers, the different IP addresses corresponds to the controllers IP addresses.

In node red I am using an UDP out node to send packets and respond to heartbeat communication but I have not figured out a way to specifically send packets from for example IP `192.168.25.43`.
I have read something about using the `bind` call to specify source address but I have not managed to figure out how it works.

I found [this](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/udp-out-node-bind-to-local-port/53636) post but I don't understand and if I try to code I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createSocket')`

Answer (score 0):

The UDP node does not allow you to set the source IP address.

The only 3 values that can be set are the destination IP address and Port and the source port.

The linked to discussion post is using a function node to send UDP packets, it first binds the `dgram` class to the [global context](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/configuration#node-configuration) by editing the `settings.js` file, which then allows the calling of the `bind()` [method](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v20.x/api/dgram.html#socketbindport-address-callback) which will allow the source IP address to be set (though the code only shows setting the source port, not the IP address)

Comment: I see.. do you know what I can do to make that function node work? Or any other way for me to make this possible..

Comment: The 3rd paragraph explains the steps to use the function node code. The only other option would be to modify the UDP node, if you do that please open a PR against the Node-RED project.